# logback-spring in java .jar is unable to read property from external properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I have developed an application that is compiled into a .jar file. Now, I want to execute the application while utilizing certain properties included within the .jar file, as well as additional external properties.

To begin with, the .jar file contains an "application.properties" file internally. Subsequently, I intend to run the application by incorporating the "external.properties" file.

However, I am encountering an issue where my "logback-spring.xml" file fails to recognize any of the properties. I have attempted to address this problem by executing the following command:

```
java -jar myapplication.jar -Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,file:external.properties
```

It appears that the "external.properties" are being loaded too late for the "logback-spring.xml" file to access. Is there a potential solution to this issue?

Comment: Can you share an example `logback-spring.xml` file that shows how you're using the properties and an example `external.properties` file that shows how you're defining them? A [complete, minimal example](/help/mcve) would be ideal.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the `variable file=...` syntax in your logback.xml
Or are you using the `<springProperty` method instead?
And are your external.properties not loaded *at all* or are they only not loaded in logback? (a simple check would be to have a logback without properties and see if your application starts up properly)

Answer (score 0):

The logback initialization occurs pretty early in the startup process, even before the Spring environment is completely set up, so any properties loaded by Spring Boot from your external file aren't available at the time logback is being initialized. Some steps to try in your case:

1. Rename your logback-spring.xml to logback.xml, and add the following to your `application.properties`

```
logging.config=classpath:logback.xml
```

2. Add the same `logging.config` property to your `external.properties` file and point it to the `logback.xml` file

```
logging.config=file:/path/to/logback.xml
```

3. Run application

```bash
java -jar myapplication.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,file:/path/to/external.properties
```

Comment: This will make things worse as `logback.xml` is loaded even earlier than `logback-spring.xml`